# Django: New Data from Database won't show in a URL redirect until I click the link again

Tags: python, mysql, django, html

My problem is that when the user creates a new record on the database in my webpage (Mysql) and the system redirects the user to the list of elements created, the new element won't show up  until I click again the link option on a section. In other words I want django to show the new results when I redirect the user to the list, here's some fragments of code I'm using:

This is the link where the user clicks to show the list after creating a new object:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
                    <a href="{% url 'microsite:myportal_list' device_serial=device_object.network_id %}" class="btn btn-default">Regresar a Listado</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the list where I show the elements from the database:

```
   {% for portal in portal_list %}                      
    <section class="search-result-item">
       <a class="image-link" href="/microsite/myportal/view/{{portal.portal_id}}">
       <img class="image" src="{% static 'img/template-icon.png' %}">
       </a>
       <div class="search-result-item-body">
          <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <h4  class="search-result-item-heading">
                                        <a href="/microsite/myportal/view/{{portal.portal_id}}">No. de Plantilla : {{portal.portal_id}} </a>
                                    </h4>

                                    <p class="description">
                                        ID Terminos: {{portal.terms_id}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3 text-align-center">
                                    <p class="value3 text-gray-dark mt-sm">
                                       {{ randomNumber|random }} visitas
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="fs-mini text-muted">
                                        Por Semana
                                    </p>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="/microsite/myportal/view/{{portal.portal_id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-info btn-sm">Ver Detalles</a>                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
       </div>
    </section>  
   {% endfor %}
```

Here's my function in views: (The object that comes from MySQL is called myportal_list)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def myportal_list(request, device_serial):
    logger.debug("views - myportal_create")
    deviceObject = CaptivePortalService.CaptivePortalService().getNetwork(device_serial)
    captive_portal_list=""
    context = {'device_object': deviceObject}
    myportal_list = my_portal.objects.all()
    context['portal_list'] = myportal_list
    number = []
    for i in myportal_list:
        number.append(randint(0, 25))
    context['randomNumber'] = number  
    return render(request, URL_MYPORTAL_LIST, context)
```

And finally there's my list of options, that is actually the only way to show the new data from the database: (even if i press F5 the new data wont show)

```
<ul id="network-option" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                        <li class=""><a href="{% url 'microsite:myportal_list' device_serial=device_object.network_id %}">Mi Portal</a></li>
                        <!-- <li class=""><a href="{% url 'microsite:device_view' device_serial=device_object.network_id %}">Configuraciones de Accceso</a></li> -->
                        <li class=""><a href="{% url 'microsite:setconfigurations' device_serial=device_object.network_id %}">Configuraciones de Accceso</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="{% url 'microsite:promotion_view' device_serial=device_object.network_id %}">Promociones</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="{% url 'microsite:termsuse_list' device_serial=device_object.network_id %}">Términos de Uso</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

The view function where I create a new record: (Im handling the response with AJAX to be able to handle messages if there's an error or if the form was submitted correctly, in this case the messages are listed in the modal footer that I posted first)

```
def myportal_create(request, device_serial):
    if request.method == "GET":
        logger.debug("views - myportal_create")
        deviceObject = CaptivePortalService.CaptivePortalService().getNetwork(device_serial)
        captive_portal_list=""
        context = {'device_object': deviceObject}
        promotion_list = promotions.objects.all()
        context['promo_list'] = promotion_list
        terms_list = use_terms.objects.all()
        context['terms_list'] = terms_list
        return render(request, URL_MYPORTAL_CREATE, context)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PortalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/microsite/myportal/list/"+ device_serial)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
```

Also I have the correct configuration to use MySQL on settings so I don't think that being the problem.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Where's the view used to post the new record, the one where you say you redirect the user?

Comment: is the second fragment, the one that starts with:
"{% for portal in portal_list %} "

Comment: No, I mean the Django view where the user creates the new record.

Comment: I edited my question with the function, but I don't think that that function is the problem, because I checked in local MySQL and all the records were created without any problem, even my system list the new records but only after clicking the link on my option lists

Comment: Ok. Is my_portal the class name of your Django model? Are you using some caching mechanism in your app?

Comment: Yeah my_portal is the name of the class in my models,, and no, I don't think Im using cache options in the app, also I realized that when I reload the page with CTRL+F5 the server invalidates my session cause it shows a message saying that the csrftoken is not valid, so I think is definitely a cache/session problem

Comment: Wait you’re saying the creation of a new my_portal object is handled in an AJAX request? You can’t send a HttpResponseRedirect back to an AJAX request.

Comment: I'm not using the HttpResponseRedirect in my AJAX response, I'll change the response from my view later, but when I redirect the user to the list I use only the url in the modal footer

Comment: How do you redirect the user? If the URL in the link is the same as the URL of the page already loaded the browser isn’t going to request anything from the server. Do you see your `portal_list` view actually being hit in your console?

Comment: Now I realize what you mean, Im printing a simple string to see if portal_list is being called and the function is called when I submit the form but that's before the modal appaers, and when I click the option in the modal to redirect the user to the list the  function is not called anymore.
What can I do to fix this?